# Do NSLog() entries take space in the app size?

Tags: ios, iphone, nslog

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663754/is-nslog-stored-on-the-device-iphone-etc-if-so-where) provides some great relevant information. But I have not followed the recommended solution which states that you should code NSLog() as follows:

```
#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
 NSLog(@"Your tests outputs");
#endif
```

My code does not use conditional group.

Now, we have some iPhones that say there is no storage left on the device and they have only our app on it (not a single other third party app). But the tricky part is, the settings say our app is only taking up space on the order of MBs.

**tldr**: Does iOS store NSLog() outside of the app sandbox? How can I delete it without deleting the app and reinstalling?

Edit: It appears that [NSLog() writes to ASL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLogv) which uses log files. And this is outside the app sandbox. Now the question is, can these log files grow too big?

Comment: No, it prints to a shared stream that all apps use

Comment: Thank you @dan. So is it possible that the ASL log files grow too big?

Comment: I would imagine that if that were the case, users would have screamed about it a long time ago